# How to develop app for existing website with database of mysql

Tags: android, ios, mysql, database, laravel

How Are You?

I am new to app development. I have a project to develop an app of already existing website, which is develop in Laravel 8. This website is online food ordering system which contains it's data of food items and other in mysql database. Plz Guide me about the best way to develop app for that website. And can I use mysql database for app data? Plz help me and also guide me about best technology to use for both apple(IOS) and android.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Well, If I were you in that case, I would use Flutter for both Android and iOS. you need to create the front end with Flutter.
So Flutter + Laravel. These frameworks are matching well, and you can find many flutter templates with laravel backend and MySQL database.
I recommend you use the Flutter food delivery theme to create wonderful front screens. The backend is already ready. wow, you can get the result.